# Restricting a Stored Procedure Parameter's Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there a way to restrict the values of a stored procedure's parameters in SQL Server 2008? It's a varchar. E.g. I wish it to be only 'Production', 'Development', or 'QA'. I wish it to error out if someone passes 'Prod', 'Dev', 'UAT', or anything else.

Comment: Have you tried adding validation logic within the stored procedure itself?  E.g. check the value of the parameter and use RAISE ERROR if it does not match your criteria.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE PROC SomeProc
  @par VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

   IF @par NOT IN ('Production', 'Development', 'QA')
     RAISERROR(N'Your Message',16,1)

  -- MORE CODE HERE

END
```

You might extent the solution by using a table to lookup valid values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF...ELSE statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `IF` blocks and the `RAISEERROR` keyword you should be able to accomplish what you want.

However, this restriction sounds like it belongs in your application versus your stored procedure.

Comment: Don't agree with the last line. If the procedure is expected to be called with a parameter from a specific list seems perfectly reasonable to raise an error if some nonsense passed in rather than assuming a default or failing silently.

Comment: I think its a fair point, I would restrict SP logic to CRUD only and have the application handle input validation.  After all the app is subject to source control, version control, code reviews etc, where as SP logic can often go unnoticed and become difficult to debug.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Unless the stored procedure is being executed at command line or by administrators using something like Management Studio, I don't see why this logic is needed in the stored procedure.  What you described can very easily be implemented in an application where business logic can be tucked away.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this would be to manually check the value yourself. As a rough example, something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @value varchar(32)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @isAllowed bit = 0
    if @value in ('Hello', 'World')
        set @isAllowed = 1

    if @isAllowed begin
        -- Do work here
    end
    else begin
        -- Send error here
    end

END
```